# GIT post-receive hook not checking out submodules

Tags: git, kohana-3

I have been working on a Kohana 3 project that I installed using the downloaded zip file awhile ago. I have a git repository on my remote server "project.git" which checks out the latest commits to the working directory "public_html" where I test the application

My post-receive hook file

```js
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/public_html;
git checkout -f;
```

which was working for a couple of months until I decided to remove some kohana folders and use git submodule instead, so I can do updates via git.

Now the problem is that the submodules are not in the working directory. I tried going in there to add the submodules but the "public_html" directory isn't a repository. In the "project.git" directory, git commands throw an error that I must perform them in the working directory.

How do I modify my hook to checkout submodules when I do a commit?

**Update**

As per @manojlds's suggestion:
I added it to the hook and now it looks like this:

```js
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/public_html;
git submodule init;
git submodule update; 
git checkout -f;
```

But I get this message,

```
remote: You need to run this command from the Top level of the working tree
```

and no changes to the submodules in

```
public_html
```

Comment: Just in case, everything is working fine locally. I just want the remote web folder to have everything I have locally

Comment: yeah I was able to reproduce your issue. See my updated answer with full post-receive hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my post-receive hook:
Replace WORK_DIR with a location where you want to checkout to. This is a main web directory in my case. It is initialized as a git repository and simply pulls from the git bare repository this hooks runs in. This solves both the checkout speed (git is much faster in checking out than cp -R from the other answer is) and also keeps submodules properly synced.

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR
echo "Checking out"
(cd $WORK_DIR && git pull --recurse-submodules=yes --force)
echo "Submodule update..."
(cd $WORK_DIR && git --work-tree="$WORK_DIR" submodule update --init --recursive --force)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the following (appropriately using the GIT_WORK_TREE environment varible):

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

so that you can get the contents of the submodules on the remote server and then copy them to `public_html`

The below is the full post-receive hook ( modified to support proper functioning of the submodules) :

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR
git clone /path/to/repo /tmp/public_html
cd /tmp/public_html
git submodule init
git submodule update
cp -R /tmp/public_html /var/www/
rm -rf /tmp/public_html
rm -rf /var/www/public_html/.git
```

Comment: yes I tried that, but it doesn't work in the project.git folder nor does it work in the public_html folder. Do I add this in the hook file itself?

Comment: @Jay8100 Yes add in the hook itself.

Comment: @Jay8100 - yeah I was able to reproduce your issue. See my updated answer with full post-receive hook.

Comment: Ahh, so all it took is to create a temporary folder to clone the repository! Thanks!

Comment: This makes push operation horrendously slow.

Comment: @Berkus, possibly if your repository is really huge. I never had problems with my repositories. Needless to say, submodules are best merged into the main repository for production.

Comment: I settled for a different, significantly faster method myself.