# Deployment with local Git submodules

Tags: git, deployment, git-submodules

Here is the current setup. I have a:

- Central Git repository (origin) on a network drive
- Working copy on my local hard drive
- Repository on the web server to deploy project to

I use a submodule to pull in a framework that is hosted on GitHub. My understanding is that when I add a subdmodule to my repository, it downloads the repository from GitHub to my local working directory, where I can then checkout the desired version, and ultimately push to the origin.

When I commit the code to the origin repository, does it push a copy of the framework as well, or does it only, for lack of a better word, store a reference/pointer to the remote repository?

I ask because I would like to create a few repositories of third-party tools that I often use with this framework (currently not managed with Git), so that I can easily pull them into the projects that need them. The goal is to then update my local, third-party repositories whenever needed and update the individual projects with a newer version.

The way I deploy my projects is by pushing them to the web server, which will then deploy the application using the `post-receive` hook. The potential problem might be that if Git doesn't push the submodule itself and only a pointer, which I think is the case, because that's what `git submodule init && git submodule update` is for, the web server will have no way of getting a copy of the submodule's contents.

The easiest solution I can think of would be to simply host those third-party tools using a public-facing service like GitHub or Bitbucket, but I'm wondering if there's another way?

Answer (score 1):

> When I commit the code to the origin repository, does it push a copy of the framework as well, or does it only, for lack of a better word, store a reference/pointer to the remote repository?

The latter: it store a [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309)), which means if you have done:

- any checkout in the submodule (ie. you have changed the HEAD but have *not* modified any file), you need to go back to the parent repo, add, commit and push that new special entry which reflect the new HEAD SHA1 of your submodule
- any *file modification* in your submodule, you need to:

  - add, commit and push that submodule back to its origin
  - go back to the parent repo, add, commit and push.

Your post-receive hook can take care of a `git submodule update --init --recursive` step.
See [this hook for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282988/6309).

Comment: +1 since this was helpful, however I'm still wondering about the best way to get a local submodule on to the remote server, if possible,  when local can push to remote, but remote can't pull from local.